# Validar si hay disponibilidad entre horas

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy realizando un sistema para la asignacion de reuniones y necesito validar antes de registrar si hay disponibilidad entre una hora de inicio y una hora final de la que ingresa el usuario y validar con las que estan en la base de datos.
Lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera.

Tengo estas horas en la base de datos
(a). 07:45 a 8:30
(b). 10:00 a 11:00
(c). 11:20 a 12:00

Si yo ingreso que deseo una reunion de 09:00 a 09:45 deberia validar 
`si mi inicio que es 9:00 esta despues de las 8:30 de la hora final en (a) y si mi hora final 09:45 esta antes de la hora de inicio en (b) daria true hay espacio`
El problema es que si yo ingreso que deseo mi reunion entre las 8:20 y las 10:00 no me validaria las 8:30 en la posicion (a).

Mi codigo es el siguiente nose como mas hacerlo pensaba en un array pero no se como lo haria.

```
public int validarHoras(CReuniones reunion) {

        conn = cn.getConexion();
        int valido = 0;

        try {
            CallableStatement validar = conn.prepareCall("{CALL Sl_ValidarHoras (?,?)}");
            validar.setString(1, reunion.getFechainicio());
            validar.setString(2, reunion.getFechafinal());

            // hrinicio & hrfin = horas que ingresa el usuario
            Date hrinicio = time.parse(reunion.getHorainicio());
            Date hrfin = time.parse(reunion.getHorafin());

            rs = validar.executeQuery();

            Date hri = time.parse("00:00:00"); 
            Date hrf = time.parse("00:00:00"); 

            while (rs.next()) {

                Date hriniciodb = time.parse(rs.getString("Sl_HoraInicio"));
                Date hrfindb = time.parse(rs.getString("Sl_HoraFin"));

                if (hrfindb.before(hrinicio)) {
                    hri = hrfindb; // Aqui se guarda la hora menor final de la db
                }
                if (hriniciodb.after(hrfin)) {
                    hrf = hriniciodb; // Aqui se guardaria la hora mayor de inicio de la db
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            conn = cn.closeConn();
        }
        return valido;
    }
```

Procedimiento en mysql

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE Sl_ValidarHoras
(
_SlFechaInicio DATE,
_SlFechaFinal DATE
)
BEGIN
SELECT Sl_HoraInicio, Sl_HoraFin FROM sala WHERE Sl_FechaInicio = _SlFechaInicio AND Sl_FechaFinal = _SlFechaFinal;
END $
```

Comment: Parece que se podría hacer desde `Sl_ValidarHoras` ¿podemos ver ese código?

Comment: Ese codigo es un procedimientoen mysql es este. lo dejare bajo la logica

Answer (score 0):

De hecho, si reflejas la lógica que planteas en la consulta del procedimiento te regresaría los horarios que se traslapan:

```
SELECT Sl_HoraInicio, Sl_HoraFin 
  FROM sala 
  WHERE Sl_HoraInicio < _SlHoraFinal
    AND Sl_HoraFinal  > _SlHoraInicio;
```

De tal manera que si te regresa algún registro significaría que la sala está ocupada.

Comment: Hola @Sal, ya lo hice de esa manera pero aún sigue sin funcionar 100% de varias maneras lo hice en mysql por eso había decidido mirar desde la lógica

Comment: De echo hay estás usando los menor y menor para las fechas y yo necesito es validar disponibilidad de horas en una fecha

Comment: La idea es que si no encuentra registros significa que esta disponible. Tu tabla es de ocupaciones, entonces es mas directo -y fácil- encontrar ocupación que disponibilidad. Una reunión ¿pude durar mas de un día?